# SELECT very slow when no results and a LIMIT is specified

Tags: postgresql, index, postgresql-9.4, performance, statistics, postgresql-performance

I am running into an issue where a `SELECT` query is very slow because it does not use an index when the number of final results is 0 *and* a `LIMIT` clause is specified.

If the number of results is greater than 0 then Postgres uses the index and the result return in ~ 1ms. This seems to always be true as far as I can find.

If the number of results is 0 and no `LIMIT` is used, Postgres uses the index and the results return in ~ 1ms

If the number of results is 0 and a `LIMIT` is specified Postgres does a sequential scan and the results take ~ 13,000 ms.

Why doesn't PostgreSQL use the index in the last case?

**Cardinalities:**

~ 21 million rows total.
~ 3 million rows `WHERE related_id=1`
~ 3 million rows `WHERE related_id=1 AND platform=p1`
2 rows `WHERE related_id=1 AND platform=p2`
0 rows `WHERE related_id=1 AND platform=p3`
~ 8 million rows `WHERE platform=p2`

**Postgres Version**: 9.4.6

**Table Schema:**

```
CREATE TYPE platforms AS ENUM ('p1', 'p2', 'p3');

CREATE TABLE mytable (
    id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('mytable_sq'::regclass),
    related_id integer NOT NULL,
    platform platforms NOT NULL DEFAULT 'default'::platforms,
    name character varying(200) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT mytable_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT mytable_related_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (related_id)
         REFERENCES related (id)
);

CREATE INDEX related_id__platform__index ON mytable (related_id, platform);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX some_other_index ON mytable (related_id, lower(name::text));
```

**Queries and plans:**

This query returns 0 rows:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE related_id=1 AND platform='p2'::platforms
LIMIT 20;

 Limit  (cost=0.00..14.07 rows=20 width=737) (actual time=12863.465..12863.465 rows=0 loops=1)
    ->  Seq Scan on mytable  (cost=0.00..1492790.47 rows=2122653 width=737) (actual time=12863.464..12863.464 rows=0 loops=1)
          Filter: ((related_id = 1) AND (platform = 'p2'::platforms))
          Rows Removed by Filter: 21076656
 Planning time: 3.540 ms
 Execution time: 12868.190 ms
```

This query also returns 0 rows:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE related_id=1 AND platform='p2'::platforms;

 Bitmap Heap Scan on mytable  (cost=60533.63..1295799.94 rows=2122653 width=737) (actual time=0.890..0.890 rows=0 loops=1)
 Recheck Cond: ((related_id = 1) AND (platform = 'p2'::platforms))
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on related_id__platform__index  (cost=0.00..60002.97 rows=2122653 width=0) (actual time=0.888..0.888 rows=0 loops=1)
         Index Cond: ((related_id = 1) AND (platform = 'p2'::platforms))
 Planning time: 0.827 ms
 Execution time: 1.104 ms
```

This query returns 20 rows (without `LIMIT` it would be upwards of 2 million rows):

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE related_id=1 AND platform='p1'::platforms
LIMIT 20;

 Limit  (cost=0.44..70.95 rows=20 width=737) (actual time=0.759..0.995 rows=20 loops=1)
   ->  Index Scan using related_id__platform__index on mytable  (cost=0.44..1217669.26 rows=345388 width=737) (actual time=0.759..0.993 rows=20 loops=1)
         Index Cond: ((related_id = 1) AND (platform = 'p1'::platforms))
 Planning time: 5.776 ms
 Execution time: 2.476 ms
```

This query returns 2 rows:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE related_id=1 AND platform='p3'::platforms LIMIT 20;

 Limit  (cost=0.44..80.37 rows=20 width=737) (actual time=0.014..0.016 rows=2 loops=1)
   ->  Index Scan using related_id__platform__index on mytable  (cost=0.44..99497.62 rows=24894 width=737) (actual time=0.014..0.015 rows=2 loops=1)
         Index Cond: ((related_id = 1) AND (platform = 'p3'::platforms))
 Planning time: 0.972 ms
 Execution time: 0.123 ms
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Postgres does a bad job estimating the frequency of the *combination* of predicates in your query:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl
WHERE  related_id = 1 AND platform = 'p2'::platforms
LIMIT  20;
```

Each of your predicates is not very selective on its own - that information is available to Postgres ("most common values") - assuming your statistics are up to date:

> ~ 21 million rows total.
>   ~ 3 million rows `WHERE related_id=1`
>   ~ 8 million rows `WHERE platform=p2`

IOW, ~ every 7th row passes the 1st filter and ~ every 3rd row passes the 2nd. Postgres does the (naive) math and expects that roughly every 20th row qualifies. Since there is no `ORDER BY`, *any* 20 qualifying rows will do. The fastest way should be to scan the table sequentially and be done after ~ 400 rows - only a few data pages, very cheap.

Using *any* indexes adds some extra cost, Postgres needs to scan index *and* table. (Exception: index-only scans, which are not possible here for your `SELECT *`). That will only pay if Postgres would otherwise have to read enough additional pages to estimate that to be more expensive. That's how I would explain that you see a sequential scan for a small `LIMIT`, but a bitmap index scan for a big (or no) `LIMIT`.

Unfortunately, the ***combination*** of your predicates turns out to be unexpectedly rare. Postgres has to scan the whole table just to find only 2 qualifying rows. (The index would actually be *much* cheaper in any case.)

> 2 rows `WHERE related_id=1 AND platform=p2`

The ***combined frequency*** of values in multiple columns is ***not*** available to Postgres. Think about it: gathering statistics like that would quickly get out of hand.

A very simple and efficient **solution** for this particular case: Create a **partial index**:

```
CREATE INDEX related_id_1_platform_2_idx ON tbl (id)
WHERE  related_id = 1 AND platform = 'p2'::platforms;
```

Not only will this super-tiny index (2 rows) be a perfect match for your query, it will also make a count estimate available for your particular combination (entry in `pg_class.reltuples`). The actual index column is mostly irrelevant for this one, pick a small column, typically best to make it the PK.

If one of the two predicates can change, there is a **more generic** approach. Say, if `related_id = 1` is the stable condition, then create:

```
CREATE INDEX related_id_1_idx ON tbl (platform)
WHERE  related_id = 1;
```

The index column is relevant again. This may not be enough to tip the scales because Postgres only collects complete statistics for index columns of *functional* indexes (else it relies on the statistics of the underlying table). I propose:

```
CREATE INDEX related_id_1_func_idx ON tbl ((platform::text::platforms))  -- double parens!
WHERE  related_id = 1;
```

Note the extra pair of parentheses - a syntactical necessity for the cast shorthand.
The expression `platform::text::platforms` doesn't actually change anything - it casts your `enum` to `text` and back. But it makes Postgres collect full statistics on the (presumed) new values.

Now, (after `ANALYZE tbl`) we have full statistics including *most common values* of `platform` for `related_id = 1`.

Check with:

```
SELECT *
FROM   pg_stats
WHERE  schemaname = 'public'  -- actual schema
AND    tablename  = 'related_id_1_func_idx';  -- actual idx name
```

And Postgres should choose the index for your case - if you repeat the *same expression in your query*. So:

```
SELECT ...
WHERE related_id = 1 AND platform::text::platforms = 'p2'::platforms;
```

Related:

- [Index that is not used, yet influences query](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/72649/index-that-is-not-used-yet-influences-query/72662#72662)

About *most common values* in the Postgres statistics:

- [Speeding up a GROUP BY, HAVING COUNT query](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/131067/speeding-up-a-group-by-having-count-query/131107#131107)